# DRF custom url for viewset method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have a rating viewset for product per user as :

```
class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RatingSerializer

    # @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<pizza>\d+)/')
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'<int:user>/<int:pizza>')
    def get_user_pizza_rating(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

how can I define the url to call this method

drf custom url actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it at the start of your `url_path` parameter

```py
class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RatingSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'get_user_pizza_rating/(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<pizza>\d+)')
    def get_user_pizza_rating(self, request, user, pizza):
        ...
```

So if your `RatingViewSet` got path `/api/ratings/`, you can get your method with url `/api/ratings/get_user_pizza_rating/<user>/<pizza>/`